# Bash script not detecting second argument

Tags: bash

I'm making a page generator in bash. When checking for argument $2 to use as title of the page i'm generating, it finds nothing and echo the "No title supplied..." line.

Here is the snippet containing $2:

```
header() {
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>" > $filename.html
echo "<html>" >> $filename.html
echo "<head>" >> $filename.html
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "No title supplied. Using name of the file."
    echo "  <title>$filename</title>" >> $filename.html
else
    echo "  <title>$2</title>" >> $filename.html
fi
echo "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\">" >> $filename.html
echo "</head>" >> $filename.html
echo "<body>" >> $filename.html
echo "" >> $filename.html
}
```

Here is the link to the full script: https://ghostbin.co/paste/p8qpx

Comment: Neither call to `header` is given *any* arguments, let alone a 2nd argument. The function cannot see the script's positional arguments, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend a command group to avoid having to constantly (re)open `$filename.html`: `{ echo ...; echo ...; ...; } > $filename.html`. The "no title supplied" line should be written to standard error (`echo "No title..." >&2`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a function, `$2` refers to the second argument of that function, not of the whole script. So you have to pass that as a parameter when calling `header`

Like this

```
header "$2"
```

Then, inside your function, it will be `$1` since it will be the first parameter of that function call.